# Accessing remote_user variable

Tags: ansible

This seems to work, but is it fragile? I want the owner and group in the files command to be set to `someguy`. I'd expect to be able to use `{{ remote_user }}` but that doesn't work.

This is an example playbook showing what I mean.

```
---
- hosts: foobar
  remote_user: someguy
  tasks:
    - name: configure /usr/src/foo
      file: 
        dest: /usr/src/foo
        state: directory
        owner: {{ ansible_ssh_user }}
        group: {{ ansible_ssh_user }}
        recurse: yes
      sudo: yes
```

This doesn't work:

```
---
- hosts: foobar
  remote_user: someguy
  tasks:
    - name: configure /usr/src/foo
      file: 
        dest: /usr/src/foo
        state: directory
        owner: {{ remote_user }}
        group: {{ remote_user }}
        recurse: yes
      sudo: yes
```

> One or more undefined variables: 'remote_user' is undefined

Comment: Where is the above defined? Where are you trying to access it? What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Is it an error? Blank value?

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 13):

There's also `{{ ansible_ssh_user }}`, which contains remote user name and seems to be accessible without issues. [See also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677811/791046).

Answer (score -4):

When specifying variables in commands, you have to enclose them in quotes - for example:

```
  file: dest=/usr/src/foo state=directory owner={{ remote_user }} group={{ remote_user }} recurse=yes
```

should really be:

```
  file: dest=/usr/src/foo state=directory owner="{{ remote_user }}" group="{{ remote_user }}" recurse=yes
```

I'm surprised your first example works at all given the lack of quotes.

Additionally, your 'remote_user' doesn't actually have to be 'someguy' in that example as usually using `sudo: yes` is sufficient to have the file module set the specified owner and group correctly.

Comment: It runs as root, and it has to, as the `/usr/src` subdirectory isn't writable by anyone but root.

Comment: Are you sure quotes are required?  I'm not seeing that in the jinja docs, and if I do that the quotes end up in the final file too (so if quotes aren't allowed in that part of the file, I'm hosed).

Answer (score -4):

You can try to write playbook like:

```
---
  - set_fact: remote_user="someguy"
  - hosts: foobar
    tasks:
      - name: configure /usr/src/foo
        file: dest=/usr/src/foo state=directory owner={{ remote_user }} group={{ remote_user }} recurse=yes
        sudo: yes
```

Comment: That's essentially the same, but I really despise side scrolling, and the cognitive load of thinking about multiple variables per line. It also fails exactly the same way.

Answer (score -4):

You can fix this by adding a vars: option

```
---
- hosts: foobar
  vars:
    remote_user: someguy
  tasks:
    - name: configure /usr/src/foo
      file: 
        dest: /usr/src/foo
        state: directory
        owner: {{ remote_user }}
        group: {{ remote_user }}
        recurse: yes
      sudo: yes
```