# Ansible remote_user vs ansible_user

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

The question is simple: what is the difference between `ansible_user` (former `ansible_ssh_user`) and `remote_user` in Ansible, besides that the first one is set if configuration file and the latter one is set in plays / roles? How do they relate to `-u` / `--user` command line options?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

They both seem to be the same.

Take a look here:

```py
# the magic variable mapping dictionary below is used to translate
# host/inventory variables to fields in the PlayContext
# object. The dictionary values are tuples, to account for aliases
# in variable names.

MAGIC_VARIABLE_MAPPING = dict(
   connection       = ('ansible_connection',),
   remote_addr      = ('ansible_ssh_host', 'ansible_host'),
   remote_user      = ('ansible_ssh_user', 'ansible_user'),
   port             = ('ansible_ssh_port', 'ansible_port'),
```

Source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c600ab81ee/lib/ansible/playbook/play_context.py#L46-L55

Besides, `ansible_user` is used when we want to specifiy **default SSH user** in ansible hosts file where as `remote_user` is used in **playbook** context.

From https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/c600ab81ee/docsite/rst/intro_inventory.rst

> ansible_user
> The default ssh user name to use.

and here is an example of using `ansible_user` in `ansible hosts` file:

```ini
[targets]

localhost              ansible_connection=local
other1.example.com     ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_user=mpdehaan
other2.example.com     ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_user=mdehaan
```

Comment: It's really sad how they have different names for the same option and which ssh user to log in as is not the only example. Since the first lesson everyone in our line of work learns is to never "break backward compatibility" and to not think for themselves, things like this will only pile up and cost the community countless of hours in wasted efforts to decipher the product usage.

Comment: Features get added that cause a need for new names; in this case, connection plugins that do not use SSH.

Answer (score 8):

One difference between remote_user and ansible_user:
When you run a role with different users from a playbook, e.g.:

```
- name: Apply user configuration to user root 
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
- name: Apply user configuration to user murphy
  hosts: all
  remote_user: murphy
```

Then you can perform a conditional task for a distinct user by using "when: ansible_user == .." but not with "when: remote_user == ..". e.g.:

```
- name: Add user murphy to wheel group
  user:
    name: murphy
    groups: wheel
    append: yes
  when: ansible_user == "root"
```

Comment: The example you show actually runs two different plays with different users, not two different roles. As far as I am concerned it is not possible for now to run different roles within the same play as different users. Here is a feature request though: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5084