# Run Ansible playbook task with predefined username and password

Tags: ansible

This is code of my ansible script .

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"
  ansible_become_pass: "{{ pass }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Creates directory to keep files on the server
      file: path=/home/{{ user }}/fabric_shell state=directory

    - name: Move sh file to remote
      copy:

        src: /home/pankaj/my_ansible_scripts/normal_script/installation/install.sh
        dest: /home/{{ user }}/fabric_shell/install.sh



    - name: Execute the script
      command: sh /home/{{ user }}/fabric_shell/install.sh
      become: yes
```

I am running the ansible playbook using command>>>
`ansible-playbook send_run_shell.yml --extra-vars "user=sakshi host=192.168.0.238 pass=Welcome01"` .

But I don't know why am getting error

```
ERROR! 'ansible_become_pass' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/pankaj/go/src/shell_code/send_run_shell.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

Please guide , what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 3):

`ansible_become_pass` is a connection parameter which you can set as variable:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ host }}"
  remote_user: "{{ user }}"
  vars:
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ pass }}"
  tasks:
    # ...
```

That said, you can move `remote_user` to variables too (refer to the whole [list of connection parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters)), save it to a separate host_vars- or group_vars-file and encrypt with [Ansible Vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/user_guide/vault.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668756/ansible-remote-user-vs-ansible-user)  and [Ansible Page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html). I propose to use `become_user` in this way:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: task/java_tomcat_install.yml
      when: activity == 'Install'
      become: yes
      become_user: "{{ aplication_user }}"
```

Try **do not** use `pass=Welcome01`,

> When speaking with remote machines, Ansible by default assumes you are using SSH keys. SSH keys are encouraged but password authentication can also be used where needed by supplying the option --ask-pass. If using sudo features and when sudo requires a password, also supply --ask-become-pass (previously --ask-sudo-pass which has been deprecated).

Comment: let me try the way you suggest me @3sky .

Comment: ansible-playbook send_run_shell.yml --extra-vars "user=sakshi host=192.168.0.238" --ask-become-pass

Comment: i run this command . and changed yaml file is https://hastebin.com/komuzavusa.coffeescript

Comment: but getting error `"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n"`  @3sky

Comment: `--ask-sudo-pass` is in situation when You login as user(with for example ssh keys) and want to sudo. For login as normal user try `--ask-pass`.

Comment: --ask-pass worked .But i have to provide password interactively is there any way . So i don't need to provide password interactively. @3sky

Comment: Store password in plain text is never good. Use Ansible Vault, or public key authentication for ssh.