# Rundeck Authentication failure on new remote node

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ssh-keys, rundeck

I  want to add the new remote node in rundeck but it has shown the in node tab  [node details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSdQ8.png) but it is giving the `Failed: AuthenticationFailure: Authentication failure connecting to node: "192.168.1.200". Make sure your resource definitions and credentials are up to date.` you can see the error message in the screenshot.
I have copied the key using ssh-copy-id user@ip and its working fine with `ansible -m ping all` from CLI but when I execute the commands from rundeck its giving error. I gave the sudo right to user and `hostkeychecking no`, I am not using the resourse.xml in `/var/lib/rundeck/project`but still facing the issue. how it could be fixed.

Comment: Hi! In your Ansible inventory, you have the users defined like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36677811/10426011 That works for me. Greetings!

Comment: thanks !!! with the above mention link, my issue is fixed.

Comment: Perfect, let me post as answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `ansible_user` (Ansible host file, usually at `/etc/ansible/hosts`) or `remote_user` (Ansible playbooks context). Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668756/ansible-remote-user-vs-ansible-user/36677811#36677811).

Also, you can define that user at Rundeck, just go to your project, then go to Project Settings > Edit Configuration > Default Node Executor (the tab, defined as "Ansible Ad-Hoc Node Executor"), put the user name on "SSH User" textbox and save.